# Use only XWiki-RenderingEngine in own Web-Application

Tags: java, web-applications, xwiki

I have a own Jetty-Server with JAX-WS and Sqlite-Database which gives nice JSON via REST. I like to integrate the possibility to use optionally XWiki if Collaboration is needed. For that i will use XWiki-REST-Service for sure.

But i ask myself if can "only" use the Rendering-API of XWiki to get more advanced content in my own Web-Application. Is that possible? Which Maven-Artifacts from XWiki do i need for this? Do you have an example?

Comment: Show what you've tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The question is: Is it possible to use the rendering-engine of xwiki in an own application? I can not show it, because i not know how to start.

Comment: Have a look at http://rendering.xwiki.org/ ; these pages even have a maven snippet to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. There are the Maven-POMs and Examples for Standalone. See http://rendering.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/GettingStarted